# UIButton with custom image not highlighting on touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton, and i am setting the image like this:

```
UIImage *menu = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-bar-button-item"];
UIImage *menuTemplate = [menu imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIImage *menuOnTouch = [menu dsk_tintedImageWithColor:[[UIColor dsk_redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7f]];
[self.menuButton setImage:menuTemplate forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menuButton setImage:menuOnTouch forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.menuButton.tintColor = [UIColor dsk_redColor];
```

However, the button does not show any highlighting or anything when tapped. I'd like to continue to use the 'tintColor' as a tool for setting the color of the button. Is there any reason why this button is not respecting the provided image for the highlighted state?

Comment: Did you try to add `[self.menuButton setImage:menuOnTouch forState:UIControlStateSelected];`